# Как получить в функции данные объекта её вызвавшего?

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылка:

```
<a title="Заголовок" href="javascript:someFunc()">ссылка</a>
```

Соответственно вызывается функция. Вопрос: можно ли в этой функции получить данные об объекте, которая вызвала функцию? В частности получить `title`, или текст ссылки?

Ссылок будет много, хотелось бы обойтись без дублирования информации из ссылки в параметрах функции.
Также, знаю, что можно присвоить ссылкам id, передавать его параметром, а в функции уже использовать `getElementById()`, но опять же, конечный пользователь не слишком умён, хотелось бы, что бы он просто создавал ссылки, а дальше всё делалось в скрипте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Способ 1. Передача `this`

```js
function foo(el){
  console.log(el.title, el.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<a title="Заголовок" href="javascript:" onclick="foo(this)">ссылка</a>
```

#### Способ 2. Обработка события.

В этом случае нужно только уточнить, какие именно объекты нуждаются в обработке.

Например, обработка всех тегов `a`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  if (el.tagName !== 'A') return;
  console.log(el.title, el.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<a title="Заголовок" href="javascript:">ссылка</a>
```

#### Способ 2+. Обработка события.

Если шаблон править нельзя, вы можете также проверять аттрибут `href`, чтобы оперировать нужными ссылками.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  if (el.tagName !== 'A') return;
  if (el.href !== 'javascript:someFunc()') return;
  console.log(el.title, el.innerHTML);
  e.preventDefault(); // отменяем действие по href
});
```

```html
<a title="Заголовок" href="javascript:someFunc()">ссылка</a>
```

#### Способ 3. `document.activeElement`

```js
function foo() {
  var el = document.activeElement;
  console.log(el.title, el.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<a title="Заголовок" href="javascript:foo()">ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Передача this параметром это для меня открытие, правда такое, о котором можно было бы и самому догадаться. Слушателя использовать очень не хочется, нерациональный, плюс опять же нужно будет прописывать отдельные классы для ссылок, конечный админ сайта не самый внимательный и умный, как мы помним. activeElement пока выглядит как самое лучшее решение, посмотрим как он будет работать в конечном коде.

Comment: Добавил вариацию ко второму способу)

Comment: Реализовал через activeElement. Работает как надо, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Не самое лучшее решение ставить функцию в тег `href`

Так лучше:

```
<a href="#" onclick="MyFunction();">text</a>
```

Так еще лучше:

```
<a href="#" onclick="MyFunction();return false;">text</a>
```

Почему так лучше? потому что это говорит браузеру что дальше, после выполнения функции, не нужно ничего делать.

Вы можете сделать так

```js
function someFunc(sender){
alert(sender.text)
alert(sender.title);
}
```

```html
<a title="Заголовок" href="#" onclick="someFunc(this); return false;">ссылка</a>
```

Comment: чем лучше? почему _Не самое лучшее решение_? В чем принципиальное отличие со способом через href?

Comment: Лучше? С каких пор `inline` вставка обработчиков лучше?

Comment: @Grundy, мне кажется что вызов функции в href как минимум это выглядит странно. К тому же в таком случае sender'ом будет window объект,а не <a> элемент.

Comment: странно не выглядит, такой подход весьма широко может использоваться. О разнице стоило как раз и написать в ответе.

Comment: Вариант с href хорош тогда, когда его можно добавить в закладки)

Comment: Смысл в том, что `onclick` я вставить не могу, ибо это шаблон, создатели, которого искренне считают, что их шаблон может формировать всё что нужно и никакие пользовательские скрипты не нужны. Если бы я делал этот сайт сам, а не на шаблоне, такого вопроса даже не возникло бы.